# YouTube Direct - Getting Started - Failure after running eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, youtube-api

i get crazy. I wanna use the google youtube direct and i have followed exactly the instruction of code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/wiki/GettingStarted

but in the end, when i´d try to run (debug) the YTD in eclipse for testing it local, i get the following failur code instead the message, that the server is available under

`(localhost:8080/)`

I have installed - jdk 1.6.0.38  & jdk 1.7.0.10
also the latest google eclipse plugin
i have adapted the appengine-web.xlm file as mentioned with my id and the developer key

i am totally lost for the moment. may you can help. thanks

`11.01.2013 22:41:39 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
11.01.2013 22:41:39 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\martin\workspace1\ytd\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
11.01.2013 22:41:39 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\martin\workspace1\ytd\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
11.01.2013 22:41:39 com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'D:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.4\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\martin\workspace1\ytd\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
11.01.2013 22:41:39 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
11.01.2013 22:41:40 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNUNG: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@4a1c2f8c{/,C:\Users\martin\workspace1\ytd\war}: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/ytd/guice/GuiceServletConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
11.01.2013 22:41:40 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNUNG: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@75b657: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/ytd/guice/GuiceServletConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
11.01.2013 22:41:40 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNUNG: Error starting handlers
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/ytd/guice/GuiceServletConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1101)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:205)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
11.01.2013 22:41:40 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
11.01.2013 22:41:40 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
11.01.2013 22:41:40 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the port of the server in which it was running, your eclipse console message says that it is running on **http://localhost:8888/** and you are trying to run it on **http://localhost:8080/**

And you can see the YTD admin under **http://localhost:8888/admin**

Comment: yes, i have also tried  http://localhost:8888/ but it is not working. when i try to "deploying ytd to google" (without any local test´s) i get the following failure message `Unable to update app: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.

See the deployment console for more details
Unable to update app: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.`

Comment: I have also downloaded the latest code of YTD, Its working fine on my side, I am using Java 6 and my Appengine SDK is 1.7.2 so might be some issue on your machine, and please make sure that you have **appengine-web.xml** in WEB-INF folder because by default from YTD is is downloaded as **appengine-web_DEFAULT.xml** so just rename it.

Comment: i use the appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4 plugin from google. and i also have rename the file to appengine-web.xml    eclipse is debuging with jdk1.6.0_38    so far it should work, but it doesnt.